# Host WPF Application online with Databinding

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

3 months ago i developed a WPF Application offline,and now i need to host this Application online.
This app gets the function to Add,Edit,Delete,Search (and so on ...) records in the database so it use a Databinding and now i need to host it online so the client can connect on the web to insert or update the data .
Can you suggest me which is the best way to host my App online using the Databinding?

Thanks so much for your attention.

..if you need more details don't hesitate to ask me . :)

Cheers

Comment: What problems are you encountering?

Comment: @Pieter ,it is the first time that i develop a Web App so before to begin this task i ask who get knowledge and experience so i can choose the best way to host my App online.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though you'd want to convert your WPF application to Silverlight. Silverlight applications run in the browser, and contain a large subset of the WPF features, including XAML and Databinding.

While it's usually not an exact 1:1 port from WPF to Silverlite, it's close. There are many resources on the topic if you Google "Converting WPF to Silverlight".

Comment: Does the convertion "WPF to Silverlight" is trustful?Anyway i will research on the Web about that.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you've used MVVM or its ilk you might be able to get away with just modifying your .XAML files without having to alter the .cs behind the view. Googling around suggests many people have had to completely rewrite their views though, [here](http://www.olsonsoft.com/blogs/stefanolson/post/Single-Sourcing-WPF-and-Silverlight.aspx) is a walkthrough by someone who's been through the process of converting their WPF app to Silverlight.

Comment: thanks for your advice,my app is very big with many features like Roles and so on ,i was looking also about WPF XBAP applications[^] because i have not so much time to do this task,What do you think about that?